# Modified Bessel function in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, gnuplot-iostream

How do I express a modified Bessel function of the second kind in Gnuplot?
I need to fit my data with the function which is included the modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Comment: With modified bessel functions you are kind of reaching the end of gnuplot, have a look at octave or maxima maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the manual? Try `help expressions functions`.

```
plot besj0(x), besj1(x), besy0(x), besy1(x)
```

or do you need higher orders?

[image]

Comment: I have checked the manual and seen these functions. But I don't know how do I convert Bessel function into its modified forms. Can you please tell how do I convert them?

Comment: sorry, I overlooked, you wrote _modified_ Bessel. Probably, you have to implement it yourself using the expression you can find here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions.  Unfortunately, it looks like gnuplot Bessel function implementation does not take complex arguments :-(, so you will end up with infinite sums... or some sufficient approximation.